# MySQL UPDATE | How to update filepath URI that saved in database

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-like

I have a table `album` that contains about 1000 rows. I want to update all rows. 
Table `album` have a column named `path`. See full table structure below.

```
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |   id    |   name    |                              path                                     |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |    1    |  Believe  | <a href="http://example.com/bollywood/Believe-1.html">Believe</a>     |
    +---------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |    2    | A Promise | <a href="http://example.com/bollywood/A-Promise-2.html">A Promise</a> |
    +---------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |    3    |  Forever  | <a href="http://example.com/bollywood/Forever-3.html">Forever</a>     |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to update `path` here. Want to add `album` in path for SEO friendly URLs. table should look like this for that goal.

```
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |   id    |   name    |                             path                                           |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |    1    |  Believe  | <a href="http://example.com/bollywood/Believe-album-1.html">Believe</a>    |
    +---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |    2    | A Promise | <a href="http://example.com/bollywood/A-Promise-album-2.html">A Promise</a>|
    +---------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |    3    |  Forever  | <a href="http://example.com/bollywood/Forever-album-3.html">Forever</a>    |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I can't figure out how to use `LIKE` here, what to insert between  `%      %`. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: LIKE will help you select which records to update, but you will probably need to use REGEX to perform the string replacement. Lookup MySQL REGEX.

Comment: Can you suggest me a way how to perform regexp here, please.

Comment: Please show us the regex you are trying and describe how it does not meet your expectations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql  So I would say you can't do it easy. maybe it is easier for you to scan through table and do it using php or python, or any other language outside MySQL server. And by the way - that  is not very best idea to store html tag in database.

Comment: But storing it in database become mendetry in my case. `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` not working and I don't wanna depend on that. I developing a project on shared hosting and latter I will choose dedicated. Then different Apache version will create a problem and I don't want puzzle like that.